# Convert DC frequency (square wave) to AC

Tags: frequency, converter, resonant-converter

I have a DC frequency generated as a square wave from a 555 at 14 kHz (actually will be using a variety of frequencies but 14 kHz is one as example) with a voltage of 4.0 V. I want to convert this to AC to connect into a car amplifier which requires an input (AC as per usual sound input) of 0.2-5.0 V.

Firstly, I'm a newbie to electronics and although I have read and re-read my books and googled for converting from DC to AC at low voltages, I am not finding anything that points me in the right direction. I see a lot of details on converting from low DC to high AC voltages.

I also maybe approaching this all wrong, but I thought if I could generate the frequency on the DC side and convert that would make sense? I'm half way there I think as I figured out the 555 and generated the DC square wave at 14 kHz.

Any pointers would be helpful. It’s a learning thing for me so pointers to where I can understand the solution and not just copy and paste are welcome.

Comment: *I have a DC frequency* No, DC means that the voltage or current is **constant over time** so the frequency is **zero**. Indeed it is clear that you're a beginner. Then it often makes more sense (to us) if you just explain **what you're trying to achieve**. So forget about AC / DC and voltages and conversions. Explain what kind of devices you have and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Tip: 'K' for kelvin, 'k' for kilo. 'V' for volt.

Comment: If you are interested in generating the variety of frequencies the 555 solution is not much suitable. Of course you can connect LC tank to 555 output but you will need to match the LC freq. with 555 freq. Then if you change the 555 freq. you also have to change one of LC component. I think the more easy way is to build one of LC  or phase shift oscilators.

Comment: Just AC couple it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a DC frequency. And this is not about converting DC to AC either.

You have a square wave with DC offset. Remove the DC offset with a capacitor in series.

Comment: The squarewave will sound like a buzzer in an audio speaker. The squarewave has a fundamental frequency plus many harmonic frequencies. A pure tone is a sinewave. A pure sinewave has a fundamental frequency with no harmonic frequencies.

Comment: @Justme and Bimpelrekkie - Thank you both! That was enough to point me in the right direction and re-read some fundamentals I obviously missed/mis-understood. Also followed up, understood and implemented removing the DC offset with a capacitor which gave me the output I expected on the scope.